Issue with @react-native-voice/voice on iOS: Stops Working After First Run
I am using the React Native library @react-native-voice/voice.
This package doesn't seem to be working correctly with the latest versions of React Native and iOS. It works properly on the first run, but once it has been stopped, it cannot be started again. No exceptions are thrown either.
Has anyone experienced the same issue or knows what the problem might be (on my end or with the package), and how to resolve it?
Note: It is working as expected on Android.
